# I want to text appear slowly-slowly last with full apha value. i am using thread to do so

Tags: android, multithreading

i want to text appear from 0 alpha to 255 alpha slowly-slowly effect. i am using thread to do this effect. Am I wrong i don't have any idea how to do this. Please give me your suggestion. 
Thanks in advance

Code is here

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread() {

            public void run(){
                try {

                    for(i =0; i <= 255; i++)
                    {
                        sleep(10);
                        displayMsg.setTextColor(Color.argb(i, 0, 0, 255));
                        Log.d("Love", "  "+ i);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        };
        thread1.start();
```

Comment: read about android animarion classes

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Why don't you use AlphaAnimation or Property Animation APIs offered by Google.